# Typescript extract knowledge from js object

Tags: javascript, cordova, typescript, webstorm

I'm creating a ionic (cordova) product and I'd like to utilize typescript and its benefits for autocompletion optimally. But since many of the plugin objects don't stem from concrete classes I don't know how/if there is a way to utilize the knowledge from the plugin files (which are .js). If there is a way to do this I'd of course like to know this.

Comment: This is a IDE specific thing isn't it? If so you might want to add the Webstorm tag...

Comment: It's at least semi IDE specific, so I've added the tag. But typescript has some build in tricks (e.g. tripple slash references) to indicate which external things are used, as far as I can see my IDE interprets this correctly, I just don't know how and if you can reference these kinds of structures.

Comment: Are you talking about [Typescript definition files](https://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Writing%20Definition%20%28.d.ts%29%20Files)? If so, you can write your own for plugins you use a lot. Sometimes searching [Definitly Typed](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) might help as well, it's _the_ source for definition files.

Comment: @Phonolog You're my hero... this is super useful. If you post that as answer Ill accept it and make people who view this happy as well.

Comment: Glad it helped! I added an answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment you can use Typescript definition files to provide type information.

There are definition files for common Cordova plugins on [Definitly Typed](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/cordova).

If you can't find type information for the plugin you're looking for, you can [write your own definition file](https://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Writing%20Definition%20%28.d.ts%29%20Files).

Answer (score 0):

> If there is a way to do this I'd of course like to know this.

Yes. Just add `allowJS` to `true` in the tsconfig.json `compilerOptions`. Your IDE should magically start working with .js files ;)

## More

Give http://alm.tools/ a go. I wrote it with such workflows in mind

Comment: If I set allowJS: true, I don't get error messages if i don't define the variables of window, but the juicy auto-completion for the plugins isn't there. Btw I'm a sucker for jetbrains IDE's so i'm using webstorm :p